# jQuery: selecting LI's parent text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a classic root structure represented in HTML by ULs (and Lis ofc.). What I need to do is that when I click on any of my LI items (or in fact  element as it contains only s) I want to get its text and text of its LIs parents.

Heres my sample of Unordered List (already wrapped):

```
<ul>
    <li class='firstLevel'><a href='#'>1</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>11</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href='#'>12</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='firstLevel'><a href='#'>2</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>21</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#'>211</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href='#'>212</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='#'>22</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#'>221</a>

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href='#'>2211</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href='#'>2212</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href='#'>222</a>

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href='#'>2221</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href='#'>2222</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='firstLevel'><a href='#'>3</a>
    </li><br>
    <li class='firstLevel'><a href='#'>4</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>41</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href='#'>42</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

For example when I click 3, I get only 3, 'cause it has no parent. But if I click on 2222 element, I should get a 2222, 222, 22 and 2 output.

My thoughts were: First, I should get a level of ULs clicked, I've done this with this code:

```
$("li").click(function (e) {
    var cnt = $(e.target).parents('ul').length;
});
```

In a cnt variable is stored level of plunge - so when I click on 2222 element, cnt = 4. (4 because root alredy returns a 1, not a zero.)

Next step is to get the texts of this parent elements. I tried to approach this elements with jQuerys .eq() function but it doesn't work correctly. Heres my test:

```
$("li").click(function (e) {
    var cnt = $(e.target).parents('ul').length;
    vat outputString = '';
    cnt--;
    for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        outputString += $(e.target).parents('li').eq(cnt).text();
        outputString += '###'; //texts separator
    }
});
```

But this approach returns all of LI item text (including his descendants) so it returns whole tree-text structure.

To summarize my question - What functions/how should I continue to get the desired output?

Heres a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/F548m/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.text` will always return the **combined** text of all descendants of an element. What you want seems to be the text of the `a` child of `li` element, not the text of the `li` element itself.

So with this in mind, this should do what you want:

```
$("li").click(function (e) {
    var text = $(this).parents('li').map(function() {
        return $(this).children('a').text());
    }).get();
    text.unshift($(this).children('a').text();
    var outputString = text.join('###');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/F548m/2/)

This gets all the `li` ancestors of the clicked element and maps them to their `a` children's text value. Then it adds the text value of the clicked elements `a` children to the begnning of the array. The order of the values is from the clicked element up to root.

If you want it the other way round, i.e. the clicked element's value last, the code actually becomes a bit simpler:

```
$("li").click(function (e) {
    var text = $(this).parents('li').addBack().map(function() {
        return $(this).children('a').text());
    }).get();
    var outputString = text.join('###');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I accepted your answer because it fits my question more as it is still click on LI element event.

Answer (score 1):

I think `.parents()` can help you

[Check demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/8AeHv/5/)

Comment: Then it's because you are doing something different, not because you are using `.parents`. Please add your code here and explain it. As I said, the OP already uses `.parents`, so telling him to use `.parents` is not very helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! @Saurabh answer as well as Felix Kling answer works for me correctly. So I dont know which one to accept

Comment: @OutOfSpaceHoneyBadger: The one that helped you the most.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the text of the `a`

```
var str=$(this).find("a:first").text();

 $.each($(this).parents("li"), function (i, v) {
        str+=", "+$(this).find("a:first").text();
 });

 alert(str);
 e.stopPropagation();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F548m/3/

Comment: Yes, I did not specify this enough. I needed a text of <a> element and couldnt get it right. Your solution is very elegant, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you should use jQuery.closest() function.

Comment: I have tried .closest() function but propably because of my structure (having <a>s inside of LIs element) it doesnt work properly. Or I have used it wrong, thats always a possibility

Comment: How would you use `.closest` here to solve the problem? Please explain.